# Android - Characters such as å,ä,ö do not render correctly in WebView

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, android-webview

I am using the following code to render my webview in android -

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "Subject: "+ getSubject() +" Content: "+ getContent() , "text/html" , "UTF-8", "");
```

The subject and content that I receive from the server are UTF encoded and show wrongly as Ã¥,Ã¤,Ã¶ in the log and on screen. However in iOS webview they show up correctly as å,ä,ö. How do I get them to show as å,ä,ö in android as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to how I was retrieving the message from the server. I was reading the Http response character by character so it broke up the encoding. When I started reading line by line it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

make sure the content you recieve, in tag <head> use like this: <meta charset="UTF-8"   >

Sorry for my English. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more of a font problem than code itself. Try putting DejaVuSans.ttf font instead of DroidSansFallback.ttf on the android itself. It should fix it. I'd search forum.xda-developers.com for a solution.

Comment: this is in the webview though

Comment: So the phone displays everything normally but webview can't? There's an option in the built-in android browser to change the encoding type, so there must be the same thing for a webview. 
I think this should help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I already specify encoding as UTF 8 in my loadDataWithBaseUrl call as specified in the reference

Comment: Yes, I saw that after posting the comment.. Sorry I couldn't help.