# Use of various language special characters in labels using xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, fonts, special-characters

I would like to know what does the correct display of special characters like italian ò à è and ù depend on.

Would it be shown correctly on any Android and iOS device?

I plan to import data from csv containing such characters from various languages.

data is then stored in sqlite and shown in labels.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this question helps you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485384/android-characters-such-as-%C3%A5-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-do-not-render-correctly-in-webview)

Answer (score 1):

There is a universe of Unicode usage (and then there is the outside). Inside, the main issue would be font support for the intended characters.

Fundamental is reading text with the same character encoding as it was written with. Whatever is loading your database would have to support that encoding, so it isn't a device issue. (Of course, that's not the only weakness of CSV. You also have to know the usage of headers, separators, text indicator and relevant escapes, decimal indicators, numeric groupings, date and time formats, line endings and column data types.)

Answer (score 0):

C# us inherently unicode.  Csv probably is 8 bit ascii so there is a problem.  Xml would be better as it could be utf.

Comment: so as long as the data is parsed correctly it should be shown on device without problem.

Comment: Maybe u could use somekind of globalisation [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview)

Comment: I don't know which section of that link you are referring to @L.Kielmann but that seems to be concerned about the ui.  I suspect hus problem will be importing data from non-unicode sources.  As long as the bytes (not chars) in the text file are converted using the correct method  (and code page ) it should be OK,  but it needs doing with good test files that exercise the converters properly. 7 bit ascii will not do here.